# Will I be considered rude if I make this statement?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Suppose I am working in private or government sector in a senior role. During evaluation of work by a junior colleague who happens to be a young woman, I find that the official is not upright, is selfish and only thinks about her own self and does not empathize with other's work or contributions in her own work.

Now if I say, "Young lady, outward appearance is always inversely proportional to inward attributes. So please improve yourself.", then will I be considered rude. Secondly, is this true in the philosophical sense?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the appropriate forum for this question is https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ . Your "philosophy" questions seem to be of a practical nature which I can only suppose relates to your professional life. There's a SE forum where people love this sort of inquiry.

Comment: Also voting to close.  But as an aside... Yes, that would be rude. Don't call an adult woman 'young lady' (unless you're her father), and never imply that anyone's professional standing is related to their physical looks.

Comment: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ Might also be a forum for you.

Comment: @J D: Thank you very much. "Young lady" was only an addition. I can use "Madam" also for a junior official. @Ted This is not related to my professional standing. I thought of posting this question in Workplace SE but then I thought about the philosophical side of being rude for a right reason that is, if it really helps in improving the work ethics of the individual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this answer is off-topic, I'll just give you a quick overview of thoughts on the matter.

In Victorian England, there was a clear dominance hierarchy among royals and non-royals, wealthy and poor, men and women, adults and children, and so on. These days, with wokeness in full swing, there's a continued effort to eradicate language that seems condescending or aggressive. Believe it or not, to call someone a lady carries certain connotations regarding male-female relationships, and while more conservative people tend not to have a problem with the use of terms like sir, ma'am, gentlemen, ladies, and the like, frequently younger, more progressive elements tend to see such language as condescending. So, when you use such Victorian-era terminology, which I suspect is probably a remnant in language particularly among those of us formerly of the British empire, there can be a visceral counter-reaction to it. I personally think it's stupid to get bent out of shape over well-intentioned uses of gender-specific terms, be they pronouns, titles, or literal vocabulary genders like actor vs. actress, some people certainly get their knickers in a twist over it.

- Use common sense. If you're addressing the Queen, mind the traditions.
- If you're employed by a woke company, be extra cautious.
- If you have a personal relationship, take that into account.
- If you are dealing with an adult of any sort, avoid any paternal or maternal patois, even if you have 40 years more experience. An 18 year-old colleague should be afforded the same level of respect as an 80 year-old one.
- If you are in a country with historical experience in castes or other stratified social communities, balance traditions against basic human decency. Not everyone is the same and maybe there are differentials in social and economic status, but there's no reason we can't be charitable with our advice (presuming it's even wanted).

Comment: "Not everyone is equal" I would rephrase it "Not everyone is the same". Using the word "equal" in this context implies having less value as being and really no one can convincingly say that to another person.

Comment: @NikosM Fair enough. Usually one talks about equality and equity.

Comment: I took the liberty to rephrase "Not everyone is identical" as it strikes me as rather unusual. If I have misunderstood your thought, feel free to revert back to original

Comment: People seem to be confused when I use the word 'hon' as a gentle way of saying I care about them. I like your emphasis on respect.